# Why we have to specify useTestNG() for tests with Gradle?

Tags: testing, gradle, testng, spock

If we want to use for our test **TestNG** we have to write something like:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':model')
   testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8'
}

test.useTestNG()
```

But when using **Spock** we specify just the dependency

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':model')
   testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
}
```

Why we have to specify `test.useTestNG()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spock tests get run via JUnit, which is the Gradle default. Alternatively, tests can be run via TestNG.

Comment: So test.useTestNG() is used to change the default Gradle test framework? Now I checked that there is  test.useJUnit() why is this needed if JUnit is the default?

Comment: `useJUnit { ... }` is only needed if JUnit-specific options need to be configured. `useTestNG()` is needed to switch to TestNG, and also to configure TestNG-specific options.

Comment: Thank, but I will continue with stupid questions (blush) if we want to use TestNG, JUnit and Spock at the same time? How to tell Gradle to use them at the same time if I write useJunit,useTestNG, the second will be the last configuration which will be taken into account?

Comment: You need separate `Test` tasks for that.

Comment: Something like
task testNGTask(type: Test) {
 useTestNG()
}
Thanks.